# Bootstrap 4 - keep width until viewport too small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a form with Bootstrap 4 and wondering if this is possible:

- When the viewport width >= 1/3 of the physical screen width, I want the form's width to stay at 1/3 of the physical screen width.
- When the viewport width < 1/3 of the physical screen width, I want the form to fill the screen width.

The form is inside a `.container-fluid` that spans the entire viewport.

(This is basically mimicing https://github.com/join)

**In case I'm asking the wrong question:** My high-level goal is to have the form stay at a good width for user interaction, unless the viewport gets too small, in which case I want the form to shrink with the viewport instead of creating a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: You can use the width and max-width properties to achieve this. For emaple, a width: 100%; max-width: 33.3%; will do something similar.

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram This doesn't make the form stay at 33% of the screen width when the viewport is larger than that though. It makes the form stay at 33% of the viewport width instead.

Comment: Using device-width is not a good aproach, for example if the view is 300px on a 800px screen, then the view is wider then 1/3 of the device width but still very small and mostly you'll not get a nice interface for the website visitor. Best practice is to use the media min-width and media max-width only .